# The use of nearly-similar words

Tags: adjectives, conjunctions

I have heard people using two words that are nearly similar or with a subtle difference. The examples include **'each and every'** & **'until and unless'**. Is it correct to use these words in English? What if I use only one word of those two in the same sentence? Does the meaning change?

Explanation with examples will be better.

Comment: Which ethics are we talking about? Kant? Socrates? Derrida? Please clarify.

Comment: I certainly don't find any "ethical" issues with redundancy, particularly when dealing with common expressions.

Comment: Nearly similar?

Comment: The queries about the use of 'ethical' rather than say 'accepted' or 'usual' here arise because the 'acceptable' sense of ethical is so much more rarely used than the 'morally correct' sense that its unqualified use here is  – let's say _unusual_.

Comment: Guys, stop having fun at expense of a learner. I'm fairly sure he meant "correct" or "accepted". @Dr Maulik V: [English for Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) may be a better site to ask such questions.

Comment: @SF. "ethical" is a very specific and peculiar word choice. "Correct" is a wishy-washy one-size-fits-all, and much more common, and more common still among learners. So this doesn't look like a slip of the tongue, but rather like a deliberate choice by the OP. My request for clarification might have been worded humorously, but it is a request for clarification nonetheless.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: depends on learner's level. "Ethical" sounds similar across a number of very different languages, while "Correct" is pretty much a germanic-only thing. If the learner forgets the correct word and seeks synonyms, "ethical" may be the first one to come to mind, wrong in this context obviously, still, easier to remember than "correct".

Comment: @SF - I'm not "having fun" at anyone's expense. That said, I was hoping my remark might be taken as a prompt to clarify and improve the question. As a side note, I believe Reg and I were typing simultaneously; his remark wasn't there when I began typing mine. I think we both had the same goal in mind, and it wasn't mockery,  it was more careful thought and expression.

Comment: @J.R. Okay, sorry for "generalizing you in" but Reg's comment seemed definitely tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: @RegDwigнt and all except SF. I thought the focus will be on understanding my question and solving it! It rather went in finding flaws! Anyway, it's corrected now. Still better clarification needed.

Comment: RE: _I thought the focus will be on understanding my question and solving it! It rather went in finding flaws!_ Not a fair comment, I don't think; that's akin to saying "answer what I meant, not what I asked." Reg and I were not "finding flaws," we were asking you to clarify your question, so that it might be answered accurately. Any and all allegations of nitpicking are misplaced.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you mean by 'ethical practice'. I don't see what would be 'unethical' about not using them. I am wondering if you meant something else.

Often these words mean almost exactly the same thing, such as 'each' and 'every'. But people simply couple them in order to reinforce a point being made e.g. 'I address each and every person here assembled', stresses that nobody is excluded.

'Unless and until' is a similar example since although the two words have different meanings, 'until' effectively overrides unless, such as in: 'Unless and until I have news, I will not be able to tell you anything'.

Comment: This type of expression involves two words comprising, usually with the conjunction _and_ or _or_, a type of collocation probably most commonly known as ['Siamese twins'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_twins_(linguistics)). There exist similar expressions where more than three words are joined, eg 'hook, line and sinker'. The fact that an alternative term for the doublet is 'irreversible binomials' shows that the ordering is non-negotiable. 'Each and every' **is** a pleonastic-looking (but used for emphasis) repetition of synonyms. 'Unless and until' **does** use non-identical twins.

Comment: To echo @Edwin's point, this practice is rather common (and therefore quite ethical, I think): _forever and always, tried and tested_, and _vigor and vim_ are a few more examples that come to mind.